# Linear $\infty$-categories $\mathrm{QC(X)}$ and $\mathrm{Perf(X)}$ of a "derived" stack $\mathrm{X}$

Tags: higher-category-theory, algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

For each scheme or algebraic stack their $\infty$-category of quasicoherent sheaves (resp., perfect complexes) on it is $k$-linear for a commutative ring  $k$. That is (by a recent result of L.Cohn), it is a $\mathrm{DG}$-category over $k$.

But what about is the base ring of of $\mathrm{QC(X)}/\mathrm{Perf(X)}$ if $\mathrm{X}$ is a "derived" stack? That is, either

$(1)$ a derived Artin stack in the sense of "derived algebraic geometry" à la Toen and Vezzosi, based on simplicial commutative rings,

$(2)$ or a spectral Deligne-Mumford stack in the sense of "spectral algebraic geometry" à la Lurie, based on $\mathrm{E_{\infty}}$-rings.

There isn't much on the matter in existing papers and literature. The impression I got from browsing some papers on derived (resp., spectral) algebraic geometry, that Toen and Vezzosi consider $\mathrm{QC(X)}/\mathrm{Perf(X)}$ for a derived Artin stack as a $\mathrm{DG}$-category (that is, a $k$-linear $\infty$-category for a commutative ring $k$) while Lurie in his book "Spectral Algebraic Geometry" seems to treat more general $R$-linear $\infty$-categories for $R$ being an $\mathrm{E_{\infty}}$-ring (however, $\infty$-categories arising from spectral Deligne-Mumford stacks are still stable).

What I'm trying to ask is the following:
Let $\mathrm{X}$ be a derived Artin stack or a spectral Deligne-Mumford stack. 
Then $\mathrm{QC(X)}$ and $\mathrm{Perf(X)}$ are $R$-linear (stable) $\infty$-category. What is $R$? An ordinary ring? A simplicial commutative ring? An $\mathrm{E_{\infty}}$-ring? Or what is the "base ring" of a derived stack?

Also, perhaps the better question would be the following: 
**Given a derived (resp., spectral) stack $\mathrm{X}$, what $R$ can be "over"?**

For example, derived Artin stacks are "built" from simplicial $k$-algebras for $k$ being a commutative ring. So even if there is a leap from commutative rings to simplicial commutative rings, ordinary commutative rings are still involved.

**P.S.** I assume that this question may seem a little naive for people who are familiar with derived algebraic geometry, but I don't know a lot on the matter, so forgive me if the question is of the low quality.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Whether QC(X) is linear over some E_infty-ring? A stupid answer is: of course, the sphere spectrum.

Comment: @DylanWilson What type of rings QC(X) is linear over? Intuition may say that over E_infinity-rings, but if we X is a derived Artin stack, apparently, QC(X) is not linear over a simplicial commutative ring, but over an ordinary commutative ring. What is more, Lurie in his "Structures Spaces" define generalized schemes (a general theory that includes ordinary schemes, algebraic stacks, derived Artin stacks, derived schemes, spectral schemes, spectral Deligne-Mumford stacks et. al) over a commutative ring k. Though he doesn't develop sheaf theory for such generalized schemes.

Comment: If X is a derived stack over k, QC(X) is a k-linear stable infinity category. This holds whether k is E_infty or simplicial commutative or ordinary discrete commutative (in which case you may prefer to think of it as a k linear dg category). Same for Perf.  geometrically this is just expressing the structure map from X to Spec k.

Comment: This question will likely attract more attention if it is clearer what you are really asking.  "But what about is the base ring of of" comes at a key point and doesn't make grammatical sense, which isn't helping.

Comment: @HughThomas Thank you for the advice. I've made an edit.

Comment: @jereckherr What is $X$ a derived stack over? The answer to this question is also the answer to yours.

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi So, there is a notion of a \infty-category linear over a simplicial commutative ring? I was under the impression that derived Artin stacks are still studied over a commutative ring, as they are built from simplicial k-algebras (k being an ordinary commutative ring). Also, Lurie in his "Structured Spaces" still considers generalized schemes (which includes both derived and spectral stacks) over a ring k (not a generalized ring).

Comment: @DenisNardin I suspected this is the case. I suppose the dual to my question is "what can derived/spectral stacks be over"?

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi Also, the notion of generalized space taken from Lurie's paper I was referring to is that: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+Deligne-Mumford+stack